# To find percentage compliance using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm not an expert in T-SQL so here I'm trying to find the % compliance for flu vaccine ,TB test and resiprator test by supervisor for medical staffs. Each employee has a supervisor name linked to their employee info. The below code works fine and it's giving me the % for the above tests. The problem is that I want to get the ID, Name and Department by Supervisor and the % compliance.

The expected output is like this:

```
Supervisor        ID      NAME     Dept      %Flu     %TB    %FIT
Elaine Jong                                   98%    100%     52%
                001       MARY   SURGERY    
                002       SUSAN  SURGERY
James Ande                                   100%     98%     78%
                267       JIM    INPATIENT
                789       SAM    INPATIENT

Current OUTPUT
                 %Flu     %TB    %FIT
Elaine Jong      98%    100%     52%
James Ande      100%     98%     78%
```

And the Query:

```
SELECT E.FLDSUPRNAME AS Supervisor,

1.0*SUM(
     CASE WHEN I.FLDDATE IS NULL 
          THEN 0 ELSE 1 
     END)/SUM(1)    AS Percent_Flu_Compliant,

1.0*SUM(
    CASE WHEN F.FLDDATE IS NULL OR (F.FLDDATE+365) < GETDATE() 
         THEN 0 ELSE 1  
     END) / SUM(1)  
AS Percent_Fit_Compliant,

1.0*SUM(
    CASE WHEN PPDx.FLDDATEDUE IS NULL 
              AND TBSSx.FLDDATEDUE IS NULL
              AND CDUEx.FLDDATEDUE IS NULL 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END) /SUM(1)   AS Percent_TB_Compliant

FROM   EMPLOYEE E

LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPT D
ON D.FLDCODE= E.FLDDEPT



LEFT OUTER JOIN IMMUNE I ON I.FLDEMPLOYEE = E.FLDREC_NUM AND I.FLDTYPE IN ('109', '111')  
AND I.FLDDATE = ( SELECT MAX(FLDDATE) FROM IMMUNE I2 WHERE E.FLDREC_NUM = I2.FLDEMPLOYEE 
AND I2.FLDTYPE IN ('109','111') ) AND I.FLDDATE >= @Flu_Date AND I.FLDDATE <= GETDATE()


LEFT OUTER JOIN FITTEST F ON E.FLDREC_NUM = F.FLDEMPLOYEE
AND F.FLDDATE = (SELECT MAX(FLDDATE) FROM FITTEST F2 WHERE E.FLDREC_NUM = F2.FLDEMPLOYEE) 

LEFT OUTER JOIN  REQEXAM PPDx
ON PPDx.FLDEMPLOYEE = E.FLDREC_NUM
AND PPDx.FLDPHYSICAL = '110' AND
PPDx.FLDDATEDUE <= getdate()

LEFT OUTER JOIN  REQEXAM PPDL
ON PPDL.FLDEMPLOYEE = E.FLDREC_NUM
AND PPDL.FLDPHYSICAL = '110' 

LEFT OUTER JOIN  REQEXAM TBSSx
ON TBSSx.FLDEMPLOYEE = E.FLDREC_NUM
AND TBSSx.FLDPHYSICAL = 'TBSS' AND
TBSSx.FLDDATEDUE <= getdate()

LEFT OUTER JOIN  REQEXAM TBSSL
ON TBSSL.FLDEMPLOYEE = E.FLDREC_NUM
AND TBSSL.FLDPHYSICAL = 'TBSS'


LEFT OUTER JOIN  REQEXAM CDUEx
ON CDUEx.FLDEMPLOYEE = E.FLDREC_NUM
AND CDUEx.FLDPHYSICAL = '109' AND
CDUEx.FLDDATEDUE <= getdate()

LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP S
ON S.FLDREC_NUM = E.FLDREC_NUM

WHERE  E.FLDCOMP = @company
   AND E.FLDSTATUS = 'A'
   AND E.FLDSUPRNAME <> ' '
   AND E.FLDID <> ' ' 

GROUP BY E.FLDSUPRNAME

ORDER BY    E.FLDSUPRNAME
```

---

If I add ID,NAME and Dept on select and group by , SUM(1) will turn to 1 or 0, so I'm getting either 100% or 0% for all supervisors.

Any help on this is really appreciated.
thanks for your time.

Comment: I've reformatted your query, but I'm still have difficulty reading it. Can you simplify the sample - perhaps you can create some CTEs or temp tables to hold intermediate results and only think about the final step? This would help with your debugging too.

Answer (score 0):

USE an UNION, add blank columns to your first query and remove the order by:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN Supervisor ELSE '' END) ,ID, name,dept,Percent_Flu_Compliant,Percent_TB_Compliant,Percent_Fit_Compliant FROM
(
SELECT E.FLDSUPRNAME AS Supervisor, NULL as ID, NULL as    name, NULL as dept
(...)
GROUP BY hiddensupervisor, Supervisor, ID, name, dept
UNION ALL
SELECT E.FLDSUPRNAME  Supervisor, E.id, E.name, E.dept,    NULL as Percent_Flu_Compliant, NULL as Percent_TB_Compliant, NULL asPercent_Fit_Compliant
FROM Employee
) as q
ORDER BY supervisor, (CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),ID
```

<s>we add the hidden supervisor column to be able to fit employees under their supervisor but leave that field blank there (we also could not add it and use case in the outer query, dunno which one would be faster).</s> Apparently we have to try with case

Comment: When I tried union all I'm syntax error. Please see the above code.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified"

Comment: @Anu I guess I should have checked it instead of trusting that everything works like in pg. If still it's bugged I ask for sqlfiddle with sample tables.

Comment: I'm not getting any error but it's not working as expected, I'm getting either blank % or 100%.

Comment: @Anu please provide example on sqlfiddle.com so I can see it.